# Open source Business Object design framework for .NET

Tags: .net, frameworks

What are the Open source options available for Business Object design framework in .NET. One we are already using is [CSLA.NET](http://www.lhotka.net/cslanet/) by [Rockford Lhotka](http://www.lhotka.net/), which is a very good framework. But I am interested in knowing other options. If anyone know any other good one please reply here.

Comment: Am I the only person that feels like CSLA.NET was written for the sole purpose to sell books about CSLA.NET?

Answer (score 1):

Try [NHibernate](https://www.hibernate.org/343.html).  It's a lot different from CSLA. NHibernate is an ORM.

Comment: Very different than the original question asks for but this is pretty much my answer, it appalls me to have to constrain my domain objects to ANYTHING other than what I explicitly want, NHibernate is really the only option for a pure POCO Domain without handrolling a custom DAL based on ADO.NET DataReaders or similar.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for Business Object design framework and a ORM, I'd recommend [PLINQO](http://plinqo.com). It has a ton of documentation, extremely quick, supports batch operations, auditing and has a rules engine.

If you are staying with CSLA, I'd recommend checking out our [CSLA Templates](http://www.codesmithtools.com/generate-csla-code-with-templates.aspx) as well. It generates a working DAL so you can focus more on the BO design and less on how you are going to populate it.

Thanks
-Blake Niemyjski (Author of the [CodeSmith CSLA Templates](http://www.codesmithtools.com/generate-csla-code-with-templates.aspx))